# Aggregation Fluent API Project method not adding Id

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to get some data from mongodb using aggregation fluent Api . i am having problem with  project method it always shows Id null with strongly type

```
var result=  await _xyz.Aggregate()
                       .Match(e => 
                       e.Id != ObjectId.Empty
                       && e.StartDate.HasValue
                       && e.StartDate >= DateTime.Today
                       && e.ABC.Any(a => abcIds.Contains(a.abcId)))
                      .Project(p => new XyzSummary()
                      {
                           Id=  p.Id,
                           Name = p.Name,
                           ABC = (List<ABC>)p.ABC.Where(a => abcIds.Contains(a.abcId)),
                           EventVenue = p.EventVenue,
                           StartDate = p.StartDate,
                           City = p.City,
                           LngLat = p.LngLat,
                      })
                      .ToListAsync();
```

Here is my XyzSummary model

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class XyzSummary 
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Abcummary EventVenue { get; set; }       
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public GeoJson2DCoordinates LngLat { get; set; }
}
```

Query is returning correct result but after projection it always shows "Id" empty if i remove class name from projection then it works fine but with class name it always shows id null

Anybody can help me please .

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried defining `Id` as string in your class and see if it maps ? Something like `public String Id { get; set; }`

Comment: yes , same issue

Answer (score 1):

why do you even use aggregation?

<s>this code will do same thing:</s>

```
var result =  await _xyz.Find(e => e.Id != ObjectId.Empty
                  && e.StartDate.HasValue
                  && e.StartDate >= DateTime.Today)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Maybe I am missing out on something. Let me know if I am =)

EDIT: I was missing something.

Comment: i am using aggregation because the collection XYZ has nested array . i want to select multiple elements form nested array . with ElementMatch we can get only first matching element . let me edit the question thanks